# Вызов функции JS непонятной конструкции

Tags: javascript

Собственно имеется функция с стороннего ресурса, пример ниже, но у нее непонятная конструкция, как её понимать, и можно ли как то вызвать эту функцию в коде?( мне известна только конструкция function a { })

```
function(a) { return "exception"}
```

Comment: покажите больше кода =)

Comment: Может Вы имеете ввиду `var x = function(a) { return "exception" }`?

Comment: pi: function(a) {
   return parseInt(a)
  }

Comment: meine скорее всего да

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ek9sGn12 вот более подробный текст

Comment: Вполне обычная функция, с вполне обычным возвратом строкового значения (разве что аргумент `a` лишний, и точки с запятой не хватает - но после последнего выражения ее можно безопасно опустить)... Что непонятного-то?

Comment: @yar85 ему непонятна анонимность объявления функции

Comment: @Igor, а, вот оно что) Спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score 1):

Эта функция находится в каком-то объекте.

Вам бы было бы понятнее если бы запись была такой?:

```
function pi(a) { 
  return parseInt(a) 
} 

let obj = {
  pi: pi
}
```

Вызвать её можно вот так

```
obj.pi("01");
```

```js
let obj = {
  pi: function (a) { 
    return parseInt(a) 
  }
}
    
let result = obj.pi("01");

console.log(result);
```